# Shifting Issue In Navigator Series in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

There is a peculiar issue i am facing when drawing live chart.
I am adding point to a series every 1 sec and shifting after 14 min.(Added shift condition  (14 * 60 + 1)).
Navigator gets points from 1st series and shifts but becomes straight line beyond 14 min.
Navigator series **data** length also becomes 0.
But Navigator series **option data** displays right length.
Please find the image in below url
http://postimg.org/image/5xxxq65cn/

Could anyone provide any input on the same ?

```
function updateChart(data) {
    var i, dateTime = new Date(data[0].TimeStamp), signalSeries, shift;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        signalSeries = chart.get(data[i].Key);
        if (signalSeries) {
            shift = signalSeries.options.data.length > (14 * 60 + 1);
            chart.get(data[i].Key).addPoint([dateTime.getTime(), data[i].Value], false, shift);                
        }
    }
    chart.redraw();
}
```

With Regards,
Tripati Patra

Comment: `series.data` may not contain all points, but only those created on demand, like actually visible, or even can be empty to get better performance. That's why you should use `options.series.data` which is containing all points from options. Also, instead of these options you can try to use `series.xData` or `series.yData` arrays, which will contain x/y-values for whole series.

Comment: Hi Pawel,I will use those (series.xData,series.yData).Dynamically I add series to the chart and for shifting each series i use individual series option data length.Is that right way ? Or Do i need to check shift condition only for 1 series and use that for other series ?But how can i solve the straight line which appears in the Navigator ?Do you have any idea why that happens ?

Comment: Unfortunately, without live demo I can only guess. Maybe you have some null points? Or a lot of points with the same value? Or instead of editing navigator series, add points to default series?